# mysqli_insert_id after commit always returns zero

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my (simplified) code.

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO Orders
  (
    UserID,
    DeliverToID,
    BillToID
  )
  VALUES
  (?,?,?)
  ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $userId, $deliveryID, $billingID);
$stmt->execute();
$conn->commit();
$orderID = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

The problem is that mysqli_insert_id always returns zero.
The Orders table has an Auto Generated column, so according to the docs, it SHOULD work.

However, I found if I move the mysqli_insert_id to before the commit, then it returns the last inserted ID just fine.
But I don't understand why and I can't find anything in the PHP online docs to explain it, apart from a comment from 11 years ago, stating the same problem, but with no plausible explanation.

Comment: The explanation has everything to do with the underlying database, which terminates a transaction on commit (or on rollback) and flushes that information

Comment: @Mark Baker I spent several hours going through the official php online docs, they don't mention any use of mysqli_insert_id with transactions.

Comment: PHP docs is not the right place, as PHP function is just an interface to mysql API function. So, you better google for the LAST_INSERT_ID() behavior

Comment: Either way, this is a very good question to ask on Stack Overflow.